# Confused about organic vs. viral page posts

Tags: facebook-pages

I manage my job's Facebook page and I'm confused about the distinction between organic and viral posts. The definitions that come up when I hover over "Organic" or "Viral" aren't clear to me. Viral posts says it's the number of people who saw the post from a friend.

But is there a way to find out how many people say the post from people that aren't my friend?

It says `465` people saw our most popular post. This was before I was an admin on the page though. A post I posted the other day got five shares and those shares got likes and comments.

If I'm not friends with the person who shared the post, does that mean it won't count as a viral view?

Ideally I'd like to know how many total people (regardless of any friend connections) viewed each post.

Is that not possible now that my personal profile is linked to the page?

Answer (score 2):

Found this on a [blog post](http://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2011/12/19/facebook-insights-what-viral-measures-tell-us-about-edgerank/), it should clarify things for you

> To recap, the viral reach of a page or a post is the number of unique
>   people who were exposed to content as a result of another user
>   generating a story (“talking about” the page or post – liking,
>   sharing, commenting, etc.). This differs from organic reach, which is
>   the number of unique people who visited the page or saw an item in
>   their news feed or ticker as a direct result of the page posting the
>   content.

As for your question

> ...but if I'm not friends with the person who shared the post, does
>   that mean it won't count as a viral view?

It should count as a viral view.